# How to avoid page refreshing on anchor element click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a dynamic website. My problem is when i click on the following  tag:

```
<a class="s-inte" href="set_interesantes.php?n=Frank Melo&u=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&back=http://localhost:8085/Something/success/profile.php?search_user=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&p=12&sa=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&i=2345123&dl=&iv=1">Interesante</a>
```

The page gets refreshed, How do I avoid this page refresh?

Comment: are you wanting the link to open the page in a different instance of the browser???  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I would like the tag play the role like facebook ones. Example: When you click on facebook anchor 'Like' the page doesnt refresh.

Comment: Why do you have a URI in the href to begin with if you don't want it to load as a page?

Comment: Well i'm a little nub on this, The file inside the href '<a>' tag get parameters via $_GET to count the interesantes(Interestings) and saves into a table, which play the role of a 'Like'.

Comment: You likely want to put that information elsewhere rather than in the href itself. As you are using jQuery, I'd suggest storing it in an HTML5 `data-*` attribute (at which point you can put `javascript:;` into the href to prevent the browser loading a whole new page.

Comment: Have never used the data- attr as i said above i'm a little nub on this, Would you make a example for me please?

Comment: you need `ajax` for this purpose

Comment: @user3236821 ah, are you not using AJAX for this? If not, then I'm afraid you maybe need to step back a bit and read up on that. There's some good answers below steering you in a good direction. Oversimplified explanation: an a/href is a link to a complete new page. AJAX is a way to communicate with the server then update a portion of a page without having to load a new page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is to update some counter of interestings w/o refreshing the page?
You should do it using AJAX techniques, this is what AJAX was invented for.

Consider the following code, it's top easy (jQuery library required):

```
<a href="#" class="counter">Interesante</a>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.counter").click(function()
    {
         $.get("set_interesantes.php?n=Frank Melo&u=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&back=http://localhost:8085/Something/success/profile.php?search_user=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&p=12&sa=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&i=2345123&dl=&iv=1" );
         .... // you can do some animation here, like a "Liked!" popup or something
         return false; // prevent default browser refresh on "#" link
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Glad to hear! If you are interested in learning AJAX, start with GET method, from this page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
And if you want any response from AJAX PHP script, it's easy as well, for example: `$.get("test.php", function(data){alert(data);});`

Answer (score 3):

you need to prevent default action on the click event.

You can do a simple inline handler which will return false

```
<a class="s-inte" onclick="return false" href="set_interesantes.php?n=Frank Melo&u=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&back=http://localhost:8085/Something/success/profile.php?search_user=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&p=12&sa=f6e79cfe9c0ecc4c08dac4c860c4802b&i=2345123&dl=&iv=1">Interesante</a>
```

or write a jQuery handler which will do the same

```
$('.s-inte').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

Comment: Tried this a while ago, doesn't seems to work in Chrome.

Comment: @user3236821 - Well it should. If it didn't then most probably you did something wrong...

Comment: didn't work for me, actually nullified my anchor links

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically loading the content using ajax. You should probably call it in this way. This way it will work for every anchor with `.s-inte` class, no matter it's added dynamically or statically.

```
$(document).on('click', '.s-inte',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do more stuff every anchor click here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).