# How to prevent page refreshing when clicking on href with "?" variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to prevent page reloading when `<a href="?gift1">` is clicked?

I'm using links to easily call php functions `if (isset($_GET['gift1'])){.....`

And that reload on every click looks kinda weird, any solutions? JavaScript? PHP?

Comment: Look into Ajax (javascript). There are plenty of tutorials for it out there.

Comment: You can use ajax and render only part of webpage

Comment: Add a click handler to the link that calls `preventDefault()` on the ClickEvent, then use `fetch()` to load stuff from the server and update the DOM. If you don't know what any of this is, try looking for a current SPA tutorial which uses a PHP backend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid page refreshing on anchor (<a></a>) tag click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359948/how-to-avoid-page-refreshing-on-anchor-a-a-tag-click)

Comment: @BrankVictoria - It's better to find a duplicate that doesn't require an extra library like jQuery since the OP hasn't tagged it.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept events with JavaScript and then prevent their default behavior, like reloading.

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('a')
  .addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.currentTarget.attributes.href.value[0] === '?') {
      // This function should stop the page from reloading.
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
```

I am not sure how that will effect your PHP behavior.